# roslaunch doesn't work

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the roslaunch tutorial, running turtlemimic.launch doesn't work, i get:

[turtlemimic.launch] is neither a launch file in package [beginner_tutorial] nor is [beginner_tutorial] a launch file name

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193235/roslaunch-doesn%27t-work/) by [DanielLSM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20267/daniellsm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-22**:
can you post the command you are using; did you save the `turtlemimic.launch` file in launch folder ?

**Comment by [DanielLSM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20267/daniellsm/) on 2014-09-22**:
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.imgur.com/BAYCAq8.png)

Have roscore running, made the source of setup.bash, beginner_tutorials is recognized as a package and roslaunch gives that error, any help?

**Comment by [DanielLSM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20267/daniellsm/) on 2014-09-22**:
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.imgur.com/BAYCAq8.png)

Have roscore running, made the source of setup.bash, beginner_tutorials is recognized as a package and roslaunch gives that error, any help?

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-22**:
see my edit above

**Comment by [Amer Al-Radaideh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29188/amer-al-radaideh/) on 2017-01-28**:
for those who have this problem ([beginner_tutorials] is not a package or launch file name)
please follow this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for answers, apparently turtlemimic.launch was not a .launch file ... fixed^^

---

Originally posted by [DanielLSM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20267/daniellsm/) with karma: 26 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it could be a stupid question, but did you created the folder with `catkin_create_pkg` before?
As explained in the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch#Using_roslaunch), it is supposed you created that folder with that command.
If you used `mkdir` or something like that, ros will never recongize the right folder.

And don't forget the `source devel/setup.bash` if you didn t automate the process after building your code.

**EDIT:**
It didn 't recognize the package in your catkin environment (your [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/BAYCAq8.png)).
Please be sure that a

> CMakeLists.txt

is in your `beginner_tutorials` package and is correctly written. Then go into your workspace:

```
daniel@daniel-G74Sx:~$ cd catkin_ws
```

and run the command `catkin_make` again.
Later on source the file devel/setup again.

It semms to me you are trying to launch the launch file from your home directory and not from the catkin workspace

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanielLSM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20267/daniellsm/) on 2014-09-22**:
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.imgur.com/BAYCAq8.png)

Yes i made the tutorials line by line without a single mistake and dind't failed until this step.
Have roscore running, made the source of setup.bash, beginner_tutorials is recognized as a package and roslaunch gives that error, any help?

**Comment by [DanielLSM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20267/daniellsm/) on 2014-09-22**:
[problem_2](https://i.imgur.com/ov2nksB.png)

In this screenshot i show that i execute catkin_make without problems, show that beginner tutorials is recognized as a package and that roslaunch still doesn't work.....